# latex pseudocode with fractions

Tags: algorithms

I´trying to write this pseudocode in Overleaf - cant do the fraction (line 15)
[image]

```
\begin{algorithm} \caption{Učící mechanismus obcí}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While {Obce ještě nedokonvergovaly}
  \State $t=t+1$
  \ForEach {$\ivar{KNIES}_p \in \tvar{Population}$}
    \For{$X_i\in\tvar{\textit{Přiřazené body}}$}
      \State $\ivar{KNIES}_p$.\quad
             \textbf{Learn}($X_i$, $\beta_t = \frac{t\beta_T}{T}$)
    \EndFor
  \EndForEach
  \If{$\ivar{KNIES_p} > \ivar{KNIES}$}
    \State $\ivar{KNIES}(t) = \ivar{KNIES}_p$
  \EndIf
  \If{$\ivar{KNIES_p} < \ivar{KNIES}$}
  \State $\ivar{KNIES}(t) = \ivar{KNIES}_p$
  \EndIf
  \State $\ivar{KNIES}(t) = \ivar{KNIES}(t)$
  \EndFor

\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable.  Since you have some responses to your old questions that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).